# How reliable is it to use abs_x / abs_y or x/y(relative) for WebElement recognition with QTP/UFT?

Tags: testing, ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to write a function to recognize a webelement which has following identification properties:

1. class
2. innertext
3. innerHTML
4. abs_x and abs_y
5. x and y (relative)

Issue is, the value for "class" keeps changing with different application updates so it can't be used for recognition.

Now, I have option to use absx/absy or x/y.
I believe x/y would be better. 
How reliable is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way!! You should not use any coordinates as properties to find an element!! 
It will not be reliable at all. Also, if you to try to run the script in another machine with different resolution, it might not work as well.

Go with 'innertext' & class name. If the class name keeps changing, does it have any pattern like class1, class2 ..etc. if yes, you can use Regular Expression.   Worst case, you can use `Ordinal identifiers`.

I would never consider coordinates in my test!!

Answer (score 0):

If possible avoid using coordinates for identification since this is very brittle (may break the test for any minor change). Obviously `abs_x` is worse than `x` since it depends on the browser's location in addition to the elements location in the page.

I would inspect the element to see if there are any properties that identify it consistently, it could be something other than the properties you listed (e.g. `title`, `role`), if possible use that rather than the location.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not true at all that use of coordinates abs_x and abs_y are always unreliable!! Hard coding them is always unreliable, but properly using them dynamically is 100% reliable.

Take the case where the only way to identify an object is by it's location in relation to another object that can be identified. Using the Object Repository, this is accomplished using the built in "Visual relationship identifier". The implementation of this same capability - visual relationship idenfication - in programmatic descriptions is accomplished using abs_x and/or abs_y coordinates.

For example, if you have an identifiable object whose abs_y value is the same as the unidentifiable object (i.e., they are consistently on the same horizontal axis or on the same axis plus or minus some number), locate the object which can be identified in the normal manner and using GetROProperty, get it's abs_y coordinate. Then, locate the other object that otherwise cannot be located, using the value of abs_y just gotten. That is, the abs_y coordinate of the identifiable object will be the abs_y value of the object that otherwise cannot be identified. Again, this is exactly what the built in Object Repository capability of "Visual relationship identifier".

Example:

```
sAbsY = Browser(...).Page(...).WebElement(...).GetROProperty("abs_y")
Browser(...).Page(...).WebElement(..., "abs_y:=" & sAbsY).Click
```